# How to connect DLNA-ready TV to PC?

Tags: ethernet, tv, dlna

I have DLNA ready Samsung TV at home. I've tested it with my router. Everything goes well.

Is it possible to connect the TV directly to a PC via ethernet cable? If so, how can configure the PC to handle it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Play movies from your PC on the TV?

Comment: exactly. but i want to connect tv directly to pc, not with router. is it possible? and if yes how to configure this connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [crossover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) network cable and fix the IP address of both your PC and the TV in the same subnet, but it would be simpler just to buy yourself a cheap router.

Comment: yes i did it. It's working now. Thx for fast reply

Answer (score 0):

If you have a router, why arent you be connecting the TV to it?  More than likely it is the router is what is providing your network connectivity, and you want everything to connect to it.

However, you *can* hook up the TV to the PC, using [Internet Connection Sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing).

My gut feeling is that you think the TV needs to be hooked up to the PC to "get your stuff."  However, the reality is the router is what everything should be connected to.

Comment: listen, currently I have no router. And i'm trying to connect tv directly to my pc. I wanna stream my pc's content to tv without router

Comment: you said you had a router in your question...

Comment: I've tested it once upon a time. CURRENTLY i have no router.

Comment: You don't need ICS for that if you don't need your TV to have internet connection. You would probably need a second network interface for your computer (e.g. a second Ethernet card).

Comment: well my answer still applies.